# Why I get wrong index on an array after applying remove( );

Tags: javascript, dom

Could someone explain to me why when I use remove(); I can't run through my arrays as I want, I mean when I want to apply changes on an arr[i], it display it on arr[i+1];

```
//adjusting the plus buton 
for (let i = 0; i < plusButton.length; i++) {
  plusButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    valueCount = ItemQty[i].value;
    valueCount++;
    ItemQty[i].value = valueCount;
    SumItemValue[i].innerHTML = ItemQty[i].value * Math.round(Number(ItemPrice[i].innerText) * 100) / 100;
    sum += Number(ItemPrice[i].innerHTML);
    totalValue.innerHTML = sum;

    //adjusting the remove button
    for (let i = 0; i < rem.length; i++) {
      rem[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

        var updatePrice = Number(totalValue.innerHTML) - Number(SumItemValue[i].innerHTML);
        sum = updatePrice;
        totalValue.innerHTML = sum;
        rem[i].parentElement.parentElement.remove();
      })
    }
  })
}
//HTML 
<div class="hoodie black-hoodie">
          <img src="./black hoodi.jpg" alt="" class="hoodie-image">
          <!--Heart emoticon-->
          
          <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
          <div class="Unity-price">
              <p class="unity-price-label">Unity Price</p>
              <span class="unity-price-value">20</span>
          </div>
          <div class="article_quantity">
              <p class="quantity-wanted">Quantity selected</p>
              <button class="btn minus-button disabled" type="button">-</button>
              <input type="text" class="quantity" value="0">
              <button class="btn plus-button" type="button">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="total-price">
              <p class="total-price-label">Total Price</p>
              <div class="total-price-value">
                  <span class="TotalValue">0</span>
              </div>
                 
          </div>
          <div class="remove-button">
            <button class="btn-remove" type="button">Remove</button>
        </div>

      </div>
```

I'm programming a shopping cart that contain a remove button,
my problem is after I remove an article, I want to refill my basket again but i get wrong results,
when I hit the remove button, after I hit the + button, the value of input underneath is updated

[image]

Comment: There is a much easier, cleaner way of doing this. Can you show a block of HTML that has the item with plus and remove buttons in it? - pls add it to your question

Comment: hello kinglish, I've add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was solved by using the Array.from method.

```
//Plus button 
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('plus-button');
//Qty entred by user 
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity');
//Minus button
var z = document.getElementsByClassName('minus-button');
//Item Price
var v = document.getElementsByClassName('unity-price-value');
//Total Price for each element
var u = document.getElementsByClassName('TotalValue');
//Total value all items
var t = document.getElementById('cart-value-value');
//remove button
var rem = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-remove');

//adjusting the plus buton
for (let i=0;i<remBtn.length;i++)
{
   //Array.from function is used to convert the like array given 
   //by getByClassName to a live array each time the remove button is clicked
let plusButton = Array.from(x);
let minusButton = Array.from(z);
let ItemQty = Array.from(y);
let UnityPrice = Array.from(v);
let ttlValue = Array.from(u);

   
plusButton[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    
   valueCount =ItemQty[i].value;
   
    //Incrementing ValueCount
    valueCount++;
    //displaying
    ItemQty[i].value=valueCount;
    
   minusButton[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
   ttlValue[i].innerHTML = ItemQty[i].value * Math.round(Number(UnityPrice[i].innerText)*100)/100;
 
   
   sum += Number(UnityPrice[i].innerHTML);
   roundSum = Math.round(sum*100)/100;
   console.log(sum);
   t.innerHTML=roundSum;
  
   
})}
//adjusting the remove button
for (let i=0;i<remBtn.length;i++)
{
   let ttlValue = Array.from(u);
   remBtn[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
       
       var updatePrice = Number(t.innerHTML)-Number(ttlValue[i].innerHTML);
       
       sum = updatePrice;
       t.innerHTML = sum;
       
       remBtn[i].parentElement.parentElement.remove();   
   })
}
```

What I understnad is that **alike-array given by getElementsByClassName are a static HTML collection and it does not update itself automatically when a div with specified className is removed, so I use the Array.from to create an array instance of my HTML collection that is updated every time I remove a div with specific Class Name.**

It worked for me, I hope my expalantions are clear and correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you define an event in the for loop. Each time the for loop runs, one more event is added. Why did you define events in for? Did you try directly onclick="function()" ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update your source arrays**

To answer your question. It's hard to say exactly since you have variables in your code that we can't see the origins of. Based on your description, it seems like you're managing your data from many `array`s. When you remove an item with the remove button, it removes the element from the DOM, *but the arrays aren't updated.*

Try adding these [array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) statements to the bottom of your remove loop. They will remove the item in question from the arrays

```
for (let i = 0; i < rem.length; i++) {
  rem[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     // ... all your current code
     rem[i].parentElement.parentElement.remove();
     ItemQty.splice(i,1);
     SumItemValue.splice(i,1);
     ItemPrice.splice(i,1); 
     // and any other arrays that utilize this i index
   })
}
```

---

**Suggested rewrite**

This code revision requires a consistent container class. I chose `product`.

In the loops below, I use relative paths for everything, thus doing away with the need for any IDs. You're welcome to keep them, but they're not required for the functionality. Everything is found by starting at the `element`s `closest` `.product` parent and searching within using `querySelector`

Note how values retrieved from the DOM are converted into numbers by prepending them with `+`.

```js
const plusBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.plus-button')
const removeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove')
const ttlOrderPriceEl = document.querySelector('#totalOrderPrice');

plusBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let prod = e.target.closest('.product')
    qinput = prod.querySelector('input.quantity')
    qinput.value = +qinput.value + 1 // taking the existing value, converting to a number and adding 1
    let price = +prod.querySelector('.unity-price-value').innerText;
    prod.querySelector('.TotalValue').innerText = (price * +qinput.value);
    ttlOrderPriceEl.innerText = +ttlOrderPriceEl.innerText + price
  })
})

removeBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let prod = e.target.closest('.product');
    let thisPrice = +prod.querySelector('.TotalValue').innerText;
    ttlOrderPriceEl.innerText = +ttlOrderPriceEl.innerText - thisPrice;
    prod.parentNode.removeChild(prod)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="product hoodie black-hoodie">
  <img src="./black hoodi.jpg" alt="" class="hoodie-image">
  <!--Heart emoticon-->
  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
  <div class="Unity-price">
    <p class="unity-price-label">Unity Price</p>
    <span class="unity-price-value">20</span>
  </div>
  <div class="article_quantity">
    <p class="quantity-wanted">Quantity selected</p>
    <button class="btn minus-button disabled" type="button">-</button>
    <input type="text" class="quantity" value="0">
    <button class="btn plus-button" type="button">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="total-price">
    <p class="total-price-label">Total Price</p>
    <div class="total-price-value">
      <span class="TotalValue">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="remove-button">
    <button class="btn-remove" type="button">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr> Order total:
<div>$<span id="totalOrderPrice">0</span></div>
```

Comment: thank you kinglish i get your point and it worked for me, but I'm new to javascript and I want to know exactly why my code do not give me what I want and how can I correct it

Comment: I appreciate that. I updated my answer to give a probable cause to your issue

Comment: @HoussemS95 - did that help at all?

Comment: Knglish, Not really, but I used the Array.from method and it worked, i'll explain it as a solution